# How to set permission to all AD users in Shareoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

I am new to sharepoint 2013, I created sitecollection in Sharepoint 2013 Foundation and have set Read Permission to few specific users.

My requirement is how to set Permission to all Active Directory users of network domain so that they can browse site pages and list etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have one Site Collection you want to share, then in the Visitor group (with read permission only) add the user `Everyone` which is equivalent to `NT Authoruty\Authenticated Users`.

[image]

But if you have several Site Collections in the same Web Application, you could add a User Policy on the Web Application, by adding `All Users (windows)` with full read permission.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When assigning/giving permission, type '***Everyone***' in the people picker. This will give the permission to all users from AD